# Motorcycle headlight only ‘working’ (flickering) with starter motor

Tags: honda, electrical, motorcycle, headlight, hornet

Running into an issue with my 2009 Honda Hornet. The headlight does not work when the engine is turned on or off (both normal and high beam). Only when I’m starting the motor I see the headlight flickering (when the starter motor is running).
The backlight and flashing lights work fine.

Was thinking it might be the relay?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I don't know this bike's electrical system, but it's possible there are two relays: one that keeps headlight bulb current out of the handlebar switch, and the other a "load-shed" relay that disables the headlight when the starter motor is running. Either might be bad.

Comment: Depending on the type of relay, the load shed could also be miswired and is only directing the light power during "start" and opposed to "run" (which would be backward. Also not knowing the wiring it's hard to say, but I'd start by checking all the lighting circuit connections for good solid seating and clean contact surfaces.

Comment: If the headlight worked correctly earlier, and no electrical work has been done on the bike, then it isn't going to be a miswired load shed relay,